# MongoDB Morphia use only custom decode converter and default encode converter

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a problem using Morphia custom converters for mapping embeded documents. In my scenario I have immutable entity with no null-arg constructor. This entity is used as embedded entity in my main entity. Because it is immutable, I should declare custom converter and override the decode method to create my entity using Builder pattern. It works fine:

```
public class MetaConverter extends TypeConverter implements SimpleValueConverter {

  public MetaConverter() {
    super(Meta.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Object decode(Class<?> aClass, Object o, MappedField mappedField) {
    BasicDBObject metaDBObject = (BasicDBObject) o;

    return new Meta.Builder(metaDBObject.getDate("created").toInstant()
        , metaDBObject.getDate("updated").toInstant())
        .setVersion(metaDBObject.getString("version"))
        .build();
  }
```

However when I attempt to create new document. It fails with:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class aaa.bbb.Meta
```

If I remove the converter everything works fine in encoding.
Is there a way to use only custom decoding feature and keep the default encoding support.

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell Morphia about your converter with `mapper.getConverters().addConverter(new MetaConverter())`